# Como descobrir qual é o primeiro ou último item do Loop em Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

Tenho o seguinte `foreach` em Laravel.

```
@foreach($values as $value)
  <li>{{ $value }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Gostaria de adicionar uma informação especial quando se tratar do primeiro item do loop.

Em algumas outras template engines, costuma existir um método específico para poder saber qual é o primeiro ou último item do loop.

Por exemplo, o Twig:

```
{% for (value in values) %}
      <li>{% if loop.first %}Primeiro - {% endif %}{{ value }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso em Laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Que eu saiba isto só existe no novo Laravel 5.3:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @if ($loop->first) // primeiro item do loop
        This is the first iteration.
    @endif

    @if ($loop->last) // ultimo item do loop
        This is the last iteration.
    @endif

    <p>This is user {{ $user->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Exemplo retirado dos [DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#loops)

No que diz respeito a loops o novo Laravel 5.3 também nos trouxe, para além destes em cima, uns metodos (da nova `stdClass $loop`) que podem vir a ser uteis, ex:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    Já demos {{$loop->iteration}} voltas de um total de {{$loop->count}} voltas
@endforeach
```

`$loop->iteration` é informação acerca de em que volta estamos no loop (conta a partir de 1), enquanto `$loop->count` corresponde ao número total de voltas (neste exemplo é a contagem total de `$users`)

Referência e mais exemplos [aqui](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/the-new-loop-variable-in-laravel-5-3)

Comment: +1, você está por dentro das novidades. Eu já tava pensando em responder :p

Comment: @WallaceMaxters estava mesmo agora a brincar com o 5.3 :P

Comment: Talvez tenha outras informações que seriam interessantes adicionar à pergunta, como [essa](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/the-new-loop-variable-in-laravel-5-3). Tem mais coisas que eu imaginava :D

Comment: Miguel, eu vou dar uma pesquisada no Laravel 5.3. Ficou muito boa a resposta. Vou conferir qual objeto ele usa na variável `$loop`, estou com a pequena desconfianca que é alguma classe que implementa RecursiveIterator.

Comment: Yap talvez seja sim, é verdade @WallaceMaxters

Answer (score 2):

O blade do Laravel nada mais é do que um jeito "bonitinho" de escrever PHP no html sem precisar ficar fazendo um monte de `<?php echo $nome ?>`

Você pode fazer o que precisa pelo index do foreach:

```
@foreach($values as $i=>$value)
  <li>
      @if($i==0)
          Primeiro
      @elseif($i==count($value)-1)
          Ultimo
      @else
      {{ $value }}
      @endif
  </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Também dá certo. Mas, como respondido pelo Miguel, há uma nova funcionalidade no Laravel 5.3.

Comment: É que ele respondeu enquanto ainda tava escrevendo rsrsrs